# Changing column name in a SQL Server table with 1000+ records

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a column and want to change its name but nothing else using query, what would be the best way of doing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
sp_RENAME 'TableName.[Your_Old_ColumnName]' , '[Your_New_ColumnName]', 'COLUMN'
```

Note: renaming column name will break your queries, stored procedures etc..

Answer (score 4):

You can use the system stored-procedure [`sp_rename`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188351.aspx):

```
EXEC sp_rename 'dbo.Test.OldName', 'NewName', 'COLUMN';
```

Here's a complete sample with your 1000 records:

```
create table dbo.Test(ID int IDENTITY(1,1), OldName varchar(10));

declare @i int;
SET @i = 0;
WHILE @i < 1000
BEGIN
   SET @i = @i + 1;
   INSERT INTO dbo.Test Values(CAST(@i AS varchar(4))+ '. record');
END;

SELECT * FROM dbo.Test;

EXEC sp_rename 'dbo.Test.OldName', 'NewName', 'COLUMN';  

SELECT * FROM dbo.Test;

DROP TABLE dbo.Test;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 EXEC sp_rename 'myColumn', 'myColumn2', 'COLUMN'
```

Answer (score 2):

Calling the stored procedure [sp_rename](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188351%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) should be the easiest and fastest way

```
USE AdventureWorks2008R2;
GO
EXEC sp_rename 'Sales.SalesTerritory.TerritoryID', 'TerrID', 'COLUMN';
GO
```